# Can not add google play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have a Problem: I made the instruction steps to import the google play services into my eclipse workspace. thats all fine. But when I add the library to my project the following happens:
I add the lib [image] [image]

Then I press apply. When I get back to the properties I see this:
[image]

And I cant add it. Maybe the reason is, that I work in my `D` drive and not `C` where java is installed?

Comment: Are google-play-services_lib and your project in same directory?

Comment: Are the library & the project in the same folder?

Comment: yes they are in the same folder. But they are under D and the java installation is under C. Maybe this is the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that can solve your issue:

1. Delete the `google play services library` from `Workspace` folder.
2. Redownload the library, make sure the library is in the workspace folder (considering your android projects are stored in the same workspace folder).
3. Add the library to the project again.

Comment: I did this, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: have you imported the library into eclipse workspace?

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to select the `Copy to workspace` option when importing the `google_play_services_lib`.

Comment: I did this, but I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Did you delete the first one before importing a new one?